# Greasemonkey if/else timeout with dates

Tags: javascript, date, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a script that refreshes a page every 10 seconds, but I want to have a different page every hour. Here's a simplified version of what I have so far using only two hour periods:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        RCS testing 12 - 21
// @namespace   cat1788@gmail.com
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function () {
  var today = new Date().getHours();
  //console.log(today);
  if (today >= 12 && today <= 13) {
      window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
  } else if (today >= 13 && today <= 14) {
      window.location.href = 'http://bing.com';
  }
}, 10000);
```

What's happening, though, is that only the first page ever starts on it's refresh cycle: what have I done wrong?

I'm new to Greasemonkey so maybe I've made a very basic mistake here, I hope you can help!

Thanks for your help,
Cat

Comment: you include that script for `http://google.com` and `http://bing.com` ... correct? BUT you need to also include the script on `http://www.bing.com` and `https://www.google.com` because the two urls you use are redirected - please show your greasemonkey metablock

Comment: of course, this script will redirect to google at 12:00:00 to 13:59:59, then bing at 14:00:00 to 14:59:59 ... probably not what the author intended

Comment: @JaromandaX yep, that looks like the issue... would it be better to have:
`if (today == 12) {//google}
else if (today == 13) {//bing}}`
?

Comment: @CatBurston: Well, use `===`, not `==` (because type coercing `==` is non-transitive and generally evil). But `getHours` returns an integer value, not a double, so even changing the test to straight equality doesn't change behavior; it still reloads every ten seconds at the specified page for a solid hour. That said, the description given indicates this is desired: "[refresh] a page every 10 seconds, but I want to have a different page every hour."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JaromandaX and @ShadowRanger, I don't need to use a period of time, I can just use the hour integer:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var hour = new Date().getHours();
  //console.log(today);
  if (hour === 12) {
      window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
  } else if (hour === 13) {
      window.location.href = 'http://bing.com';
  }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Off-topic: Maybe use `hour` instead of `today` as a variable name? Since this is about the hour, not the day? Also, if you're doing a different site for every hour of the day, consider a [`switch` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Comment: Also note: As written, if you _don't_ handle every hour of the day, when a page is loaded more than 10 seconds before one of the handled hours, it won't reload once you enter one of the handled hours until another reload occurs. If you're not handling all hours, and you want to change behavior as you enter a new hour, use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` (for ease), or calculate a proper timeout to the next handled hour (harder, but doesn't involve constantly rechecking; admittedly a small cost when the check is only once per 10 seconds).

Comment: Good points, @ShadowRanger. I updated the variable name to be more helpful. For setInterval/Timeout, it's not so necessary for my needs, but good to know if I need this script again in the future!
Thanks for your help